# How to show that $\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi$ goes to 0 if $\psi$ is are not both left/right handed?

Tags: dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices, chirality

How do you show, using the Dirac matrices, that the above expression is $0$? I have tried substituting $\psi^{\dagger}\gamma^{0}$ in for $\bar{\psi}$ but I cannot find any identities linking $\gamma^{0}$ and $\gamma^{\mu}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\psi_L\equiv \frac{1-\gamma^5}{2}\psi\equiv P_L \psi$ and $\psi_R\equiv \frac{1+\gamma^5}{2}\psi \equiv P_R\psi$, $\implies \psi_L +\psi_R =\psi$, so
$$
\overline{\psi_L} ~\gamma^\mu \psi =(P_L\psi_L)^\dagger \gamma^0 ~\gamma^\mu \psi   =\overline{\psi_L} P_R~\gamma^\mu \psi  \\ 
=\overline{\psi_L} \gamma^\mu P_L \psi = \overline{\psi_L} \gamma^\mu \psi_L ,
$$
and likewise for the *R* spinors. The left projector, $P_L^2=P_L$, has to slide past ***two*** gamma matrices, $\gamma^0$ and $\gamma^\mu$, so  its $\gamma^5$ gets to keep its sign, and $P_L$ maintains its identity, to quash the *R* component of the right spinor.

Note this is exactly the opposite if $\gamma^\mu$ is missing, as in a mass term bilinear: There, $P_L$ flips to $P_R$ in its journey to the right, and *only* connects *L* to *R*  components, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is it that we can introduce a right projection operator on line two?

Comment: I updated the answer with the intermediate steps you asked for. Clear now?